# Suzuki Liana 2003, Sounds very loud in engine and won't increase rpm?

Tags: engine, engine-load

I got a Suzuki Liana 2003 1,6 5D that has gone 145000 Km. The engine oil was changed at 140000 km. Air filter cleaned according to instruction since it was new. Oxygen sensor new and working properly (checked with multimeter and diagrams).
Couple of weeks ago I accidentally  spill some oil an the engine and I believe it got the generators belt. but this problem occurred before it as well. Accidentally when I was on highway I realized when I try to reduce the gas the car shakes. and decrease the rpm fast. and when I try to press the gas pedal the rpm won't go upp. I stopped the car and tried to investigate. Everything seemed okay. When I tried to run the car I realized it wouldn't increase in rpm again and when I change the gear it would shut down. I finally found some parking place and I tried to test by pressing the gas pedal and I saw it wouldn't go above 2000RPM with no gear on. and it is on idle it is around 500Rpm and it slowly shuts down.

When pressing the gaspedal fully down the engine sounds very louder than expected and feel like it will explode any time soon. It sounds like there is a big hole in the engine. The whole car smells like petrol.

I got some videos that you can see. I don't get any fault codes and no engine light is on. I bough new ignition cables but no success.

[Video 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7yf63e3c5w01be7/VID-20170721-WA0000.mp4?dl=0)

[Video 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8f4f4bp3t4oxzpo/20170730_193309.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: Try pulling the upstream o2 sensor and see if it clears up. Kinda sounds like an exhaust restriction.

Comment: Ive done that too. No difference.

Comment: I'd start with the basics then. Check your battery, engine cranking compression, fuel pressure etc... Maybe do an injector pressure drop test.

Comment: Ive looked at the pressures and battery level using obd reader. Everything is according to manual however the manual's reference values are valid only on idle situation and not always